# Unable to register custom pipe globally in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have a custom pipe which does some 'stuff'

```
@Pipe({name: 'doSomethingAwesome'})
export class DoSomethingAwesomePipe: implements PipeTransform 
{...}
```

I then have two modules `Module1`, `Module2`, for each module the declarations array looks like this:

`declarations: [DoSomethingAwesomePipe,...]`

When I start the application I get the following error:

> metadata_resolver.js:369Uncaught Error: Type DoSomethingAwsomePipe is
>   part of the declarations of 2 modules: Module1 and Module2! Please
>   consider moving DoSomethingAwsomePipe to a higher module that imports
>   Module1 and Module2. You can also create a new NgModule that exports
>   and includes DoSomethingAwsomePipe then import that NgModule in
>   Module1 and Module2.

So I do exactly what it describes and create a `PipesModule` in the declarations for the module I set it up like this `declarations: [DoSomethingAwesomePipe,...]`

I then import this module in both `Module1` and `Module2` then I get the following error:

> zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The
>   pipe 'doSomethingAwesome' could not be found ("

I'm really stumped. I've tried moving the import to the root module instead but not getting anywhere.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export `DoSomethingAwesomePipe` from `PipesModule` and then import `PipesModule` to `Module1` and `Module2`:

```
...
declarations: [DoSomethingAwesomePipe,...]
exports: [DoSomethingAwesomePipe]
...
```